# Eclipse doesn't want to run my xml as TestNG test

Tags: xml, eclipse, testng

I'm using Eclipse and testNG, when I want to run my test suite I click on the arrow of eclipse to run the a class. It opens a dialogue box where I can choose `Run as a TestNG Suite` or `XSL Transformation`. I select TestNG Suite and everything goes well.
But I just created another xml file with a different name and when I click on the arrow, it runs the `XSL Transformation` and I don't know how to run the `TestNG Suite` from this new xml.
When I rename this file with the name of the other xml file, i can run it as a TestNG Suite.
How should I configure my system to have multiple xml that can be ran as a TestNG Suite?

Thank you

Comment: There's some other issue - you can run any named xml as a testng suite as long as it's a valid suite inside.  What names are you keeping and what are the contents in the file that is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to click on the green play button (drag down menu), select `Run Configurations...`

[image]

select the TestNG group and then press the `new`button on top of the groups

you can now create your testng run configuration.

[image]